# R cron job failing with data.table package

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, datatable, cron

I am running a cron job scheduling from Centos with crontab on `EC2 AWS` and `R Studio`.

When I run my script directly on `R Studio` on AWS, everything works fine, `rbindlist` function (from `data.table` package) is read correctly.

I am using this function to `rbind` multiple `dataframe`s having a name starting with "table_".

But when I use crontab to schedule my script, it fails and gives me this error:

> Error in rbindlist(mget(ls(pattern = "^table_\d+"))) :    could
>       not find function "rbindlist" Execution halted

Why it works when manually lauching the script but fails when launched through scheduling with cron ?

Help much appreciated!
M.

Comment: Does your script include `library(data.table)`? If not, then it is not surprising that it does not work via `cron`.

Comment: Try calling `rbindlist` function as `data.table::rbindlist`

Answer (score 0):

I am shameful to admit that I had put library(data.table) and then removed it and forgot... Thanks @Ralf Stubner !